# Uppercase package names when updating meteor to 0.9

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I get the following when running meteor update on my project. I'm currently on meteor 0.8.2. I tried using mrt migrate-app first, but I also had problems with that. How do I solve the problem with package names? Thanks

meteor update
=> Errors while scanning packages:

While reading package from `/packages/HTML5-History-API`:
error: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "H".

While reading package from `/packages/Planet`:
error: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "P".

While reading package from `/packages/mini-pages`:
package.js:16:7: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "H".

While reading package from `/packages/router`:
package.js:21:9: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "H".

Comment: Unfortunately all those packages need to be renamed if you want to use them in Meteor >= 0.9.

Comment: So I've renamed Planet and HTML5-History, but I don't understand the problem with router and mini-pages

Comment: Check out the `package.js` file at given location, perhaps a package with wrong name is listed as a dependency?

Comment: Even after deleting every package from the packages files, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Also remember that most of the packages got prefixed with the maintainer's nickname or "mrt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what solved my problems was removing all packages from the file .meteor/packages, updating meteor to 0.9.x and then readding the packages. Earlier I was editing the wrong packages file (the one used by npm).